# Using nrgrok with CNAME on a DNS server

Tags: dns, ngrok

I am using ngrok to be implemented in my automated testing. My plan is to create a tunnel for local front-end and back-end so I can have a container in the cloud running some E2E tests in local machine.

I create a functional tunnel from my backend to a concrete link.

Now this communication from my container is going through a DNS server with a CNAME changing the url that the application is trying to access to the ngrok one.

So the connection is

> app-api.abc.net -> DNS(app-api.abc.net:1234.abc.com) -> backend

When connection is done through the DNS, I get a message:

> Tunnel app-api.abc.net not found

Comment: did you find a solution ?

Comment: No, I was researching for a week and I couldnt find any solution within ngrok.

Comment: Yes, with ngrok free account, it is not possible. you need to have basic paid service to avail HTTP tunneling with dns registration possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your own domain such as `app-api.abc.net`, you should pay pro plan.

1. Created the domain with your custom domain.
2. Run ngrok command with `-hostname` option.

For example,

```sh
ngrok http -region=us -hostname=app-api.abc.net 80
```